# How to play background music and video of other app at the same time in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, music

In iPhone, it is possible to play background music and video app at the same time?
For example, I played background music using AVAudioPlayer framework. It works as well before other video or music app run. But as soon as other video or music app run, this background music is stopped. 
I want to play background music and other video or music app together in iPhone. How can I play these together?

Comment: Is this a development question?  If so, it should be on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)  That said, there's no running of background tasks in iOS so your video or music won't play.  iOS does provide for background app refreshing as documented here:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks

Comment: Normally, is it possible to play background music and other sound at the same time in iPhone? This is not development question. Can I play background music and other sound or video at the same time?

Comment: Short answer?  No.  It’s not possible.

Comment: Can you explain more why not?

Comment: I can play these in android. But I couldn't play in iPhone. I am not sure why it is impossible in iPhone. Please explain more.